# Do I need to purchase another Sims games to play The Sims 4: Get to work?

Tags: pc, the-sims-4

Do I need to purchase all the Sims games to play The Sims 4: Get to Work (expansion pack)?

I already tried to install the the game to my computer and it is saying that I need another game but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to purchase the actual game, what you have brought is an expansion pack. You can purchase The Sims 4 from Walmart for $40.

Answer (score 1):

You need to purchase the basic game but i think walmart is kinda expensive... i usually check the prices from http://www.pccdkeys.com where they compare the prices from many stores so you buy from the store with lowest :P